# Delete SNS topic but only if there are no subscribers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I need to delete an AWS SNS topic after I delete the last SQS queue subscribed to it. However, I cannot first request the subscriber list, look at its length, and then delete the topic. If I do that, another worker might have swooped in and subscribed a new queue in between my list subscription and delete operations.

Is there a way to do an atomic delete if no subscribers operation on SNS topics?

Comment: interesting question but this does not appear to be possible, if you control the clients you may be able to set tags or something of that nature to mark a topic as a candidate for delete and then have client check this before adding subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think is to

- Deny new subscription by using IAM policies to the SNS Topic
- Delete all the SQS Queues subscribed
- Delete the SNS Topic

Comment: I don't want to deny new subscriptions though. I just don't want to delete it if any new subscriptions manage to be created.